# How to get route parameters before the response in Lumen middleware?

Tags: lumen, lumen-5.4

I'm using Lumen 5.4 and I need to get a route parameter and process it to every request, so I've created the following middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class StoreMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {        
        $store = $request->route()[2]['store'];

        $map = Config::get("mapping.stores");
        if(isset($map[$store])){
            Config::set(["data.stores" => $map[$store]]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => "Invalid store '$store'",
                'valid_store_list' => array_keys($map)],404);
        }

        $response = $next($request);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the $store variable is only set if I put the $next($request) before it, but this means that I cannot get the data set by Config::set on my controller, since the controller will now be processed before the middleware.

In other words what I'm trying to achieve is to process urls like:

- domain.com/store1/costumers/
- domain.com/store1/sellers/
- domain.com/store2/costumers
- domain.com/store2/sellers/

Ths is my web.php file (didn't made sellers yet):

```
$app->group(['prefix' => '/{store}/costumers/', 'namespace' => '\App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    $app->get('/','CostumersController@index'); //get all the routes    
    $app->post('/','CostumersController@store'); //store single route
    $app->get('/{id}/', 'CostumersController@show'); //get single route
    $app->put('/{id}/','CostumersController@update'); //update single route
    $app->delete('/{id}/','CostumersController@destroy'); //delete single route
});
```

I'm stucked in this for a while and couldn't find a solution. Am I doing anything wrong, or this is impossible to achieve with Lumen?

Answer (score -1):

Write following line of code to get the requests coming for any route,

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class StoreMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{        
    //your all requests coming from route
    $all = $request->all();

    //for any specific field or condition
    if($request->input('age') < 18){
       //return some error or handle code
    }       

    $store = $request->route()[2]['store'];

    $map = Config::get("mapping.stores");
    if(isset($map[$store])){
        Config::set(["data.stores" => $map[$store]]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => "Invalid store '$store'",
            'valid_store_list' => array_keys($map)],404);
    }

    $response = $next($request);

    return $response;
}
}
```